# Creating bigquery connection for airflow using config file

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to create bigquery connection. Below config is present in a yml file

```
  gcp-conn:
    conn_type: google_cloud_platform
    conn_extra: '{ "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":"/usr/local/airflow/key.json", "extra__google_cloud_platform__project": "<project_name>", "extra__google_cloud_platform__scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"}'
```

Command: `inv create-airflow-connections --env-file <yml_file>`

Connection gets created but when i browse it from UI, leads me to an oops page with error:

> Error:
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 3054, in on_form_prefill
>       value = d.get(field, '')
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it wants something like

```
    - conn_id: bigquery-warehouse
      conn_type: google_cloud_platform
      conn_extra:
        extra__google_cloud_platform__project: "my_google_cloud_project_id"
        extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path: "usr/local/airflow/service-account.json"
        extra__google_cloud_platform__scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    - conn_id: google_cloud_default
      conn_type: google_cloud_platform
      conn_extra:
        extra__google_cloud_platform__project: "my_google_cloud_project_id"
        extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path: "usr/local/airflow/service-account.json"
```